# BDS Abnormal Program termination (macOS build)

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using Delphi 10.2.3. I was building for OSX without issues yesterday (I thought). Now every time I try to do a build for OSX (SDK for OSX 10.14), I get an Abnormal Program termination and the BDS is blown away. Occasionally I get a List Index Out of Bounds (48) error - If I do not make the 10.14 SDK Active. Of course if I do make it active the BDS is blown away with Abnormal Program Termination

This is now 100% repeatable. I thought the install might be corrupt, but there is no repair option that I see, just a complete uninstall and reinstall, want to avoid that if I can (and not even sure that would fix the issue).

I see in the 10.2.3 release there was an issue that was supposedly fixed:

RSP-19828:
Compiling for OSX results in "Abnormal Program Termination" (bds.exe)
Compiler, Compiler\Delphi, FireMonkey

But this issue was just that XCode was not installed on the client side macOS system. I can confirm that XCode is running on the macOS VM and that apps created previously with Delphi 10.2.3 could be deployed and did run, so something has changed, but I have no idea what? or more importantly, how to find it.

Because this was working a few days ago, ie. I could build and deploy to macOS (see my other question WRT getting a Dylib to respond), I've wound the VM back a week or so to an earlier snapshot JUST to make sure, but still getting the error. The code is trivial, a screen with a button, it was working fine two days ago, I still have the version that built and deployed sitting on the macOS VM. So that sort of points to the macOS side? So I tried it with my physical macbook (which again was working last week) and exactly the same when doing a build, abnormal program termination and the BDE is blown away. So, back to square one, obviously something I'm doing wrong on the Windows/Delphi side?

As a test I created a completely new project with nothing, ie.just a blank screen. It blows the BDS away whenever I try to compile or build. It's an absolute b1ocker. I've posted on the Embarcadero site, but so far nothing.

FWIW, Delphi 10.2.3 and the OSX SDK is 10.14 which, according to the Embarcadero documents is correct.

Any ideas how I might get over this?

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: I edited your tags. You are not using XE.

Comment: Try deleting the scratch-dir folder on your Mac, i.e. something like: /Users/Kevin/PAServer/scratch-dir (where "Kevin" is whatever the user name is)

Comment: I am having the exact same issue since today, after the Mac updated xcode and commandline tools (real MAC, not vm). Now whenever I try to compile for osx, I get also the Abnormal Program Termination and the IDE just vanish. This has NOTHING to do with the MAC itself. Even the MAC is off, it does that, it cannot compile/link for OSX with the 10.14 sdk.

Comment: @David Heffernan, Thank you

Comment: RE: delete scratch-dir Thank you, tried that no difference @Softtouch, Good (bad for you) that's where I was heading. XCode update (10) dictates the SDK (10.14) and that's what I think has changed. I was using SDK 10.13.6. So I think the SDK 10.14 is broken (for Delphi). I have wound back High Sierra on my macOS VM to 10.13.6, but that didn't change the SDK Xcode generates (10.14). So I Deleted Xcode 10 and am installing Xcode 9.4.1 (IIRC) which builds the SDK for 10.13.6 (from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ ). I'll let you know if it fixed anything.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that XCode SDK 10.13 WORKS and XCode SDK 10.14 Dos not work.

**Notes:**

1. It is possible to install different versions of XCode
   simultaneously, I did not
2. XCode version 9.4.1 would probably run on
   High Sierra 10.14, I rolled back my VM to High Sierra 10.13.6 to be
   sure

**EDIT:** I can confirm that the Apps generated using SDK 10.13 work on High Sierra 10.14 (so no need to roll back your VM from 10.14 to 10.13.6).

This is what I did, step by Step:

**On the macOS VM:**

1. Rolled back the macOS VM to High Sierra 10.13.6
2. Installed XCode 9.4.1 (Generates SDK 10.13.6)
3. Installed XCode Command line tools for XCode 9.4.1
4. Deleted the folder PAServer\scratch-dir
5. Started the PAServer

**On the Dev VM**

1. Deleted the OSX 10.14 SDK
2. Added the (now) OSX 10.13 SDK
3. Created a simple project (just a form)
4. Built that project
5. Deployed that project

**On the macOS VM:**

1. Located the Project.app
2. Ran the project and it worked

I repeated the building and running of a more complex project and it worked perfectly, no sign of the Abnormal Program termination (BDS) error.

Comment: Yes, I deleted xcode 10 with cmdline tools, installed manually xcode 9.4.x with matching cmdline tools and it works fine. I am running osx 10.14 high sierra, on a real MAC, not a VM, so its the 10.14 SDK causing issues during linking (compiling is ok, but when it links it kills the IDE).